# Calling jQuery functions using call or apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

I want to set the value of this input:

```
$("input").val.call (this, "hi");
```

jQuery throws an error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Why is this happening? How can I call a jQuery function using `apply` or `call`?

I guess the problem is `this` that is `window` in case above. What value must take `this` here?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Hym/2/)

Comment: This will work: `$("input").val.call($("input"), "hi");`, although I don't see why you would need to use this method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to access these functions dynamically. That's why `call` or `apply` are required.

Comment: I understand that, but from the information in the OP, you already know the element selector, the function to call and the value. Why do you need to use `call` or `apply`? `$(selector)[functionName](value)` would work, assuming `selector`, `functionName` and `value` have valid values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The passed parameters are dynamically set, also. That was just an example to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that `this`.

The scope should be the jQuery object `$("input")`. So:

```
var myThis = $("input");
myThis.val.call (myThis, "hi");
```

The `undefined` problem is that jQuery internally will try to call other jQuery functions on that scope object. And your `this` (that is probably `window`) does not have them.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$.fn.val.call($("input"), "hi");
```

All jQuery methods can be found as `$.fn.METHOD`. When you call them the normal way, the jQuery object is the context; when you use `.call()` you have to pass the context explicitly as the first argument.

Comment: I like this - thanks for my "something new" of the day.  Tbh, I'm not sure why I'd ever use it but the nerd in me is loving it :)